# why is rspec giving EISDIR

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ok so I'm writing a spec for my play method...which looks like this...

```
      def play
        #draw the board
        puts drawgrid

        #make a move
        turn = 0

        9.times do
          if turn.even?

            @player = @player_h.move_human("X", @board)
            @move = @player.to_sym
            @marker = @player_h.boardpiece

            does_move_exist(@move,@marker)
            is_a_human_win

          else

            @player = @player_c.move_computer("O", @board)
            @move = @player
            @marker = @player_c.boardpiece

            does_move_exist(@move,@marker)
            is_a_computer_win

          end

         puts drawgrid

         turn += 1

        end
      end
```

my spec currently looks like this...

```
      describe 'play method'do
        it 'draws game board to screen' do
            @game.play.should_receive(:puts) == <<-EOF.gsub(/^ {6}/, '')

          a  | |  
          ----------
          b  | |  
          ----------
          c  | |  
          ----------
            1 2 3
          EOF
        end
      end
```

But the error I'm getting is this....

```
      1) Game class play method draws game board to screen
         Failure/Error: @game.play.should_receive(:puts) == <<-EOF.gsub(/^ {6}/, '')
         Errno::EISDIR:
           Is a directory - spec
```

Not sure what RSpec is telling me. How do I test that the play method 'puts' drawgrid?

Answer (score 0):

Try with @game.play.should_receive(:puts).with(@game.drawgrid)